# Retries and DLQ Pushing Not working from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have configured AWS Lambda such that all errors go to DLQ. It already has 2 retries by default, after which it should push the data to DLQ. Earlier, everything was working fine and it retries 2 times and then it was sending data to DLQ. But now, all of a sudden, it stopped working. Now, it is retrying when it is throwing an exception. What could be the reason?

This is the snippet of code where I am throwing error intentionally.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    eventSource = event['Records'][0]['EventSource'] . ## On this line, error will be thrown as the message I am sending does not abide by this format and it is giving KeyError.
    ....
    ....
    ....
```

I don't know what should I check? Is there any restriction on kind of exceptions AWS Lambda retries and send to DLQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem why it was happening. It was because in AWS Lambda, I was testing with Test configuration settings which is a sync invocation. While if we call lambda function properly from SNS or SQS, then it would be event invocation. And in case of event invocation only, lambda retries are possible.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html